# php inside html

Tags: php, html, performance

What is more effective in the matter of performance (and why)?

```
$s = "<div>";  
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)  
    $s.= "<p>".$i."</p>";
$s.= "</div>";
echo $s;
```

or

```
<div>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
<p> <?php echo $i; ?> </p> 
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt there is any appreciable difference,  they are both require O(n) operations but the 2nd one looks like a train wreak.

Comment: I use the first method with a template system.  The second is just nasty to me.

Comment: Performance is not an issue in this case: Readability is much more of an issue, and in this case, neither alternative is readable.

Comment: They both stink for readability. Separate your business and display logic as much as you can.

Comment: Performance doesn't matter, but if you really want to know which one is faster, test it? The second seems 3-4 times slower in a quick test I ran, but I wouldn't really trust those results since I ran via the CLI which has no output buffering. In a real scenario, I wouldn't expect either to make a difference.

Comment: @Matt: can you provide some details about what template system you use?

Comment: @fwielstra : what is your readable alternative then?)

Comment: @Acute, I made my own template system :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option looks cleaner and it should be more efficient, as it does less work than the other: why use `<?php echo "<div>"; ?>`" when `"<div>"` is enough?.

But, being honest, the difference in performance is minuscule, almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

There will be no difference in the same way that there will be no difference in running around the world and running around the world plus one meter.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no difference in performance, but this way your code may be a little more readable, specially if you're going to use any other loops or conditions.

```
<div>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
  <p> <?php echo $i; ?> </p> 
<?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this were Javascript the second example would run literally 50 times faster due to DOM manipulation behavior, however since this is Server Side there will be no difference save the overhead of additional computation in the first example. If I had to choose, I would choose the second for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is given and that there were comments on readability, this is my answer for readability, icya:

```
<?php

$s = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    $s .= "<p>" . $i . "</p>";

$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
<div>$s</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

echo $html;
```